# Setting file paths with Lua/C++

Tags: c++, lua

I have xml profiles stored in a folder that are switched dynamically. But the behavior is absolute path and I need a relative path. The lua code is written to work with both windows paths (back slashes) and with mac paths (forward slashes).

On my mac the path might be /folder/folder/profile1.xml. In normal application the program will return a file/location of profile1.xml. And it will find the next profile in the same folder.
If I direct the application to a new folder using a relative link such as ../profile2.xml then the program will find the new profile and returns the file/location as ../profile2.xml. Then it will not find the next profile within the same folder... it's either looking for the next profile out a step (../) or within the original folder as set by the application. I want it to find the next requested profile within this new folder location.

The existing code that sets the current profile and profile path is this:

```
local loadedprofile = '' --set by application
local profilepath = '' --set by application and modified below
```

The relevant switching functions seem to be:

```
local function setDirectory(value)
profilepath = value
end

local function setFile(value)
if loadedprofile ~= value then
doprofilechange(value)
end
end

local function setFullPath(value)
local path, profile = value:match("(.-)([^\\/]-%.?([^%.\\/]*))$")
profilepath = path
if profile ~= loadedprofile then
doprofilechange(profile)
end
```

I'm thinking I might need to modify the match criteria of the third function to remove the ../. Maybe something like this removing the optional .'s

```
local function setFullPath(value)
local path, profile = value:match("(.-)([^\\/]-([^%.\\/]*))$")
profilepath = path
if profile ~= loadedprofile then
doprofilechange(profile)
end
```

I really have no clue as to how to write this code, I'm just trying to tweak this open source code (MIDI2LR) to suit my needs. In my rudimentary understanding of the code it seems the match criteria is overly convoluted. But I would like to know if I am reading it right. I interpret it as:

```
:match("(.-)([^\\/]-%.?([^%.\\/]*))$")
(.-) --minimal return
(  )$ --from the end of profile path
[^\\/]- --starts with \ or \\ or /, 0 or more occurrences first result
%.? --through, with dots optional
[^%.\\/]* --starts with . or \ or \\ or /, 0 or more occurrences all results
```

If I am reading it right it would seem the first "starts with" is entirely redundant, or that the "from the end" should be associated with the second "starts with."

I have commented out the setFullPath function without the desired results which makes me think that a match requirement might be needed added to the setDirectory function.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am in way over my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your reading of the match is incorrect, here is a more accurate version:

```
:match("(.-)([^\\/]-%.?([^%.\\/]*))$")
(.-) -- Match and grab everything up until the first non slash character
(  )$ -- Grab everything up until the end
[^\\/]- -- Starts with any character OTHER THAN \ or /, 0 or more occurrences first result
%.? -- single dot optional in the middle of the name (for dot in something.ext)
[^%.\\/]* -- Any character OTHER THAN . or \ or /, 0 or more occurrences
```

A few notes - `%.` is a literal dot. `[^xyz]` is the inverse class, so every character other than x, y, or z. `\\` is actually just one backslash, this is due to the escaping in a string.

This simpler version would break it in a similar way that is easier to work with: `value:match("(.-)([^\\/]+)$")`

You may want to provide more information on the profile loading behavior, its hard to tell what you need the code to do. What value would path and profile have in the example you give?

Comment: Thanks @Adam B. Your explanation makes more sense that the lua.org reference I was using (http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html), particularly in reference to the ^. I understood the literal dot. And I understand the \ escape, but I was expecting the % escape to be applicable w/in the function string.

_This simpler version would break it in a similar way that is easier to work with: value:match("(.-)([^\\/]+)$")_

Comment: I actually rewrote it similarly 'match("(.-)([^\\/]*%.?)$")' But I can see that the optional literal dot isn't really required as it is a character already included. In both rewrites the literal dot is left out of the "other than" statement... for the same functionality wouldn't the literal dot need to be included?

Comment: Your newer version is functionally equivalent since the `[^\\/]*` will greedy match the rest of the line anyhow. The %.? at this point would just be at the very end and isn't required so it gets left out.

Comment: I think you are asking what the values of path and profile are in the 'local path, profile = value:match..' line

Since profilepath = path I believe it is the path set in the user settings. I.e. /applications/adobe/plug-ins/profiles/basic. And the profile would be whatever is currently loaded i.e. profile1.xml.

Comment: I currently have one profile w/in the basic folder, and multiple profiles w/in the profiles folder. Currently when it changes profile it is reference to the basic folder, looking there. I do not now the exact results, but if I use a relative link to back it out into the profile folder it reports that the loaded profile is ../profile2.xml and it is lost... it does not find the other profiles w/in the profiles folder. 

I want it to "rehome" in whatever folder it is currently located in.

Comment: In that case I think the current code is putting the ..\ in as part of the filename, which means it wouldn't be stored as part of the path. The changed regex you mentioned should fix that though since it does not look for periods. Does it help?

Comment: I'm getting the same results. And I've tried adding the other than literal dot to the front side of the original match w/o affect.